# Tables not joining in Kohana 3.1 ORM 

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

How do I get this to work?

```
$stuff = ORM::factory('mytable')
    ->with('user')
    ->with('other_stuff')
    ->find_all();
```

I've got all of my relationships set up and everything seems to be working when I do other queries. However, in the query above it is not joining table **users** to **mytable**. I think it may be because there can be many users for one **mytable.**

In the reference there is a method called `join()` which I think I might need to use here, but they don't give ***any*** information on it, and the stuff I've searched for on here does not work.

When I try to use `join` instead of `with`, it tries to join the table, but it doesn't include any "join on" information, just gives an empty `()`.

I know my ORM DB relationships are all set up correctly, so I'm a bit baffled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kohana has decent documentation, not looking in the right place is ... well, your problem.

`ORM::with()` is used for loading one-to-one (belongs to and has one) relations, though you have all the [Database_Query_Builder](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder) methods to use with ORM on your disposal:

```
$stuff = ORM::factory('mytable')
        ->join('users','LEFT')
        ->on('users.mytable_id','=','mytables.id')
        ->find_all();
```

Comment: That was it. I was missing the `->on()` stuff. /sigh. I didn't realize that you could use DB Query Builder methods with ORM. I'm learning Kohana as I go, and there was nothing in the documentation about that! But now I know, and I thank you very much for your help! -Brian

Comment: A quick followup question... I'm getting the correct DB results back from all the "with" tables, but nothing from the "joined" table. How do I get one field's data from the users table in addition to the others? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * from table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
AND table2.flag = 'Y' 
AND table2.siteid = '12'
WHERE table1.siteid = '12'
```

How the above query is written in ORM format of kohana? Is the below one is correct

```php
$stuff = ORM::factory('table1')
    ->join('table2','LEFT')
    ->on('table1.id','=','table2.id')
    ->on('table2.flag','=','Y')
    ->on('table2.siteid', '=', '12')
    ->where('table1.id', '=', '12')
    ->find_all();
```